# Cannot trace out why this regex code runs infinite

Tags: java, regex

I just copied from [oracle.com](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/test_harness.html) website and made a slight changes(altered console to System.out) and I compiled.

**But it runs infinitely.**

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

class RegexTest {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        while (true) {

            Pattern pattern = 
            Pattern.compile("int");

            Matcher matcher = 
            pattern.matcher("int void int mathint");

            boolean found = false;
            while (matcher.find()) {
                System.out.printf("I found the text \"%s\" starting at " +
                   "index %d and ending at index %d.%n",
                    matcher.group(), matcher.start(), matcher.end());
                found = true;
            }
            if(!found){
                System.out.printf("No match found.%n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`while(true)` will keep running until you `break;` out of it.

Comment: Or until an exception is thrown.

Comment: Yes, and they should also be caught and handled accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

well, you have a `while (true) {` in your code - that 'might' be an infinite loop :D